# UIView transitionWithView swift syntax

Tags: ios, uiview, swift

Can some help me with the syntax of the transitionWithView in swift. in objective-c I would use it like so:

```
[UIView transitionWithView:[ self view ] duration:0.325 options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseOut animations:
 ^{
     // do the transition
 }
 completion:
 ^( BOOL finished ){
    // cleanup after the transition
 }];
```

However I can not get the completion handler to work.
thanks

Comment: I recommend to read more about closures in _Swift_: https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/swift/conceptual/swift_programming_language/Closures.html

Answer (score 26):

it would be like this in **Swift 5.x**:

```
UIView.transition(with: self.view, duration: 0.325, options: .curveEaseInOut, animations: {

    // animation

}) { finished in

    // completion

}
```

Comment: For those coming in the future, the completion block can now be written as: `completion: { finished in //write code here }`

Answer (score 10):

I'd like to add to the accepted answer that you can pass multiple options into `transitionWithView` by passing an array like so:

### Swift 3, 4, 5

```
UIView.transition(with: status, duration: 0.33, options:
       [.curveEaseOut, .transitionCurlDown], animations: {
           //...animations
       }, completion: {_ in
           //....transition completion
           delay(seconds: 2.0) {

           }
   })
```

### Swift 2.0

```
 UIView.transitionWithView(status, duration: 0.33, options:
        [.CurveEaseOut, .TransitionCurlDown], animations: {
            //...animations
        }, completion: {_ in
            //....transition completion
            delay(seconds: 2.0) {

            }
    })
```

### Swift 1.2

```
UIView.transitionWithView(status, duration: 0.33, options:
        .CurveEaseOut | .TransitionCurlDown, animations: {
            //...animations
        }, completion: {_ in
            //transition completion
            delay(seconds: 2.0) {

            }
    })
```

and of course you can use the fully qualified syntax like this as well:

```
[UIViewAnimationOptions.CurveEaseOut, UIViewAnimationOptions.TransitionCurlDown]
```

Answer (score 7):

### Swift 3

```
UIView.transition(with: someview,
                                    duration:0.6,
                                    options:UIViewAnimationOptions.transitionFlipFromLeft,
               animations: {
                   // do something
           }, completion:{
               finished in
               // do something
           })
```

Answer (score 4):

[the docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIView_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/UIView/transitionWithView%3aduration%3aoptions%3aanimations%3acompletion%3a) are a little tricky to find, but this should work:

```
UIView.transitionWithView(self.view, 
                 duration:0.325,
                  options: options:UIViewAnimationOptions.CurveEaseOut,
               animations: {
                             …
                           },
               completion: {
                             finished in
                             …
                           })
```

You could use a [trailing closure](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/swift/conceptual/swift_programming_language/Closures.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH11-XID_126) if you wanted for the `completion` handler, but I wouldn't in this case, it would be too messy/unclear.

But if you weren't going to pass an animations block, it would be borderline readable:

```
UIView.transitionWithView(self.view, duration:0.325, options: options:UIViewAnimationOptions.CurveEaseOut, animations: nil) {
    finished in
    …
}
```