# How to animate (fade) UILabel textColor in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift

```
UIView.animateWithDuration(self.fadeTime, delay: 0, 
    options: UIViewAnimationOptions.AllowUserInteraction, 
    animations: { [weak self] () -> Void in
    var randomIndex = Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(CONSTANTS.MainColorScheme.count)))
    self?.startButton.titleLabel!.textColor = CONSTANTS.MainColorScheme[randomIndex]
    }) { (stuff Bool) -> Void in
}
```

This doesn't seem to work...it just "jumps" to the next color. It doesn't fade.
However, if I apply the same approach to `self.view.backgroundColor`, my code works.

Is there an alternative?

Comment: Try `UIViewAnimationOptions.TransitionCrossDissolve` in place of animation options.

Comment: Similar question http://stackoverflow.com/q/2426614/746347

Comment: Check out this article http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:PuadPDYxc1MJ:https://corecocoa.wordpress.com/2011/10/04/animatable-text-color-of-uilabel

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`UILabel.textColor` does not support animation. But you can animate `CATextLayer`:

**Swift**:

```
let textLayer = CATextLayer()
textLayer.string = "Your text"
textLayer.foregroundColor = yourFirstColor
textLayer.frame = yourButton.bounds
yourButton.layer.addSublayer(textLayer)

UIView.animateWithDuration(1) {
    textLayer.foregroundColor = yourSecondColor
}
```

**Objective C**:

```
CATextLayer *textLayer = [CATextLayer layer];
[textLayer setString:@"Your text"];
[textLayer setForegroundColor:yourFirstColor];
[textLayer setFrame:yourButton.bounds];
[[yourButton layer] addSublayer:textLayer];

[UIView animateWithDuration:1 animations:^{
     textLayer.foregroundColor = yourSecondColor;
}];
```

Comment: He wants the solution in swift, you can modify your answer!

Answer (score 1):

Indeed, the `UIView.animateWithDuration` will work with `UILabel backgroundColor`, while for the `textColor` it won't because color doesn't animate with UIView animations. Then, how to achieve?

**Solution 1:**

You can go for `CATextLayer` instead of a `UILabel` and then animate the color. For objective-C you can refer to this - [iPad: Animate UILabels color changing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3944416/ipad-animate-uilabels-color-changing)

**Solution 2:**

You can use `NSTimer` and decrease the `UILabel` alpha as the time passes

**Solution 3:**

Or simply you can go for "FadeIn - FadeOut" animation with `UIView.transitionWithView`

Answer (score 0):

Try this..

```
UIView.transitionWithView(YOURLABEL, duration: 0.325, options: UIViewAnimationOptions.TransitionCrossDissolve, animations: {

    // animation...

}, completion: { (fininshed: Bool) -> () in

    // completion...

})
```

Also check for other syntax [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24413539/uiview-transitionwithview-swift-syntax)

Cheers! :)