# How to animate UIlabel from bottom to top in Swift 1.2

Tags: ios, swift, animation, uiviewanimation

I want to animate the label from bottom to top when opening a view controller.

Can I Animated the label Without frameworks or pod file?

Comment: Provide what have you tried so far please...

Comment: sorry my method is totally wrong?Can i Animated the label Without frameworks or pod file.

Comment: Of course you can! you have to be more specific, what are the starting and ending points? do you use constraints?

Comment: I am fresher of swift. no i am not using constraints

Comment: You can use UIView animation of it. It is easy way to animate your UILabel.

Comment: Thanks sir i will try sir

Comment: have you found your answer @VigneshJ

Answer (score 9):

There's no need to use frameworks or pods for what you are trying to accomplish. You can simply use the following method and tweak the duration and distance to fit your needs.

```
    UIView.animate(withDuration: 2, delay: 0, options: [.curveEaseOut], 
    animations: {
        label.center.y -= self.view.bounds.height - 100
        self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
    }, completion: nil)
```

The "-100" is there so that you don't animate the label out of the view completely. If your label starts closer to the top you will need to increase this number and vice versa

Comment: Thank for your response sir.But I am animate the label only. Not Animate the uiview

Comment: This should only animate the label, have you tried the above code? The key part is where "label.center.y" is changed. You should replace "label" with the name of your label

Comment: @VigneshJ May I ask one reason you are using Xcode 1.2?

Answer (score 1):

Here transition example with Swift 1.2, [from another question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31127653/948445).

**Swift 3, 4, 5**

```
UIView.transition(with: status, duration: 0.33, options:
    [.curveEaseOut, .transitionCurlDown], animations: {
        //...animations
}, completion: {_ in
    //....transition completion
    delay(seconds: 2.0) {

    }
})
```

**Swift 2.0**

```
UIView.transitionWithView(status, duration: 0.33, options:
        [.CurveEaseOut, .TransitionCurlDown], animations: {
            //...animations
     }, completion: {_ in
            //....transition completion
            delay(seconds: 2.0) {

     }
})
```

**Swift 1.2**

```
UIView.transitionWithView(status, duration: 0.33, options:
        .CurveEaseOut | .TransitionCurlDown, animations: {
            //...animations
     }, completion: {_ in
            //transition completion
            delay(seconds: 2.0) {

     }
})
```